# Access 03 Parent and Child linkage issue

Tags: ms-access, parent-child, subform

I have an Access database (2003 Access) that has a main form linked to a table (tblClientMaster) and a series of subforms.  TblClientMaster has a series of unique client names.  You can then click on each subform (there are labels with each name that can be clicked on which will open the subforms) and they should filter based on the client you have selected on the main form.  I can't filter the subforms based on additional criteria, but I've basically given up on this for now (filter the subform results based on the value of a field on the main form along with an additional parameter, like product name.  Every attempt I've made has utterly failed and posting questions on here about it generated no responses, so I've abandoned this for now.)

I am focusing on getting a single subform to work right now (fsubBenCalcs).  Each record of the tblBenCalcs has the name of the client which matches the client name listed on tblClientMaster.  When you click the BenCalcs subform, it filters the results by client and you can cycle through each record that exists with the same client name. (for instance, Company ABC has 25 calculations that have been completed.  Once you select Company ABC, you can click on the BenCalcs subform and it will display the first record and you can cycle through the other 24)  However, when I open the main form, it asks me to enter the Parameter value "tblCalculations.Forms!frmMain!ClientName".

First, I don't understand why it is looking for tblCalculations.Forms when tblCalculations is a stand-alone table containing the data for fsubBenCalcs.  Second, when I load the main form, it should be completely independent of any value on fsubBenCalcs.  Only when I load fsubBenCalcs should it look to the main form for the name of the client.

On the Subform/Subreport (when I go into properties on the main form and find the BenCalcs subform) it has the fields "Link Child Fields" and "Link Master Fields".  For these, I put [Forms]![frmMain]![ClientName] for Link Child Fields.  For Link Master Fields I just have ClientName.

I have to imagine something is wrong in here, but I haven't been able to come up with the correct way to link these forms.  I would appreciate any help or guidance on this.  I hope I was clear enough in my description.

Answer (score 0):

Subforms (child) must link to the main form (parent).  Subforms are not designed to refer to each other in a partent-child relationship.

You can hack this as follows:

Put a text-box on the main-form (i.e., NOT any of the sub-forms) with the following control source:

```
=[subForm_1].[Form]![FieldYouWantToLinkBy]
```

Then, in your "child" sub-form, use the parent-child linking fields to refer to this textbox.